# Multiple line key in YAML

Tags: yaml

Is it possible to have a multiple line key like this?

```
mykey:
  - >
    key
    one:
    keytwo: val
```

where keyone is treated as one key. I want to parse the yaml to yield:

```
{ mykey: [ { keyone: { keytwo: val } } ] }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have a multi-line key in YAML, but not quite in the way you describe. In a YAML mapping you can split the key and value onto separate lines by prefixing the key with `?` and the value with `:`, like so:

```
? foo
: bar
```

The above would yield a data structure like `{ "foo": "bar" }` in JSON. The YAML spec calls this an *explicit* key (whereas the usual `foo: bar` style is *implicit*). When you use the explicit style, the key can be *any* YAML data structure, including multi-line scalars:

```
mykey:
  - ? key
      one
    : keytwo: val
```

...but, like all multi-line scalars in YAML, even though lines are merged, one space will be preserved between the content of each line, so the above will result in a data structure like the following JSON:

```
{ "mykey":
  [ { "key one":
      { "keytwo": "val" }
    }
  ]
}
```

So you end up with `key one` instead of `keyone`, which isn't exactly what you wanted. But it's the closest you're going to get with YAML.

Comment: I didn't know `explicit` syntax but this was what I was looking for. Spaces are not matter in my case, so your example works perfectly for me. Thanks!